# How to convert txt to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, txt

Can someone please explain me why the code to transfer this txt.file to dictionary is the answer that I written below, because I don't understand the flow.

task : convert this txt file to dictionary

house_price.txt=

```
land, building, distance_to_center, price

70, 50, 15, 500

70, 60, 30, 400

70, 60, 55, 300

100, 50, 30, 700

100, 70, 25, 1000

100, 70, 50, 650

120, 100, 20, 2000

120, 80, 50, 1200

150, 100, 50, 1800

150, 90, 15, 3000
```

answer:

```
file_house_price = open("house_price.txt", "r")

data_house_price = file_house_price.readlines()

file_house_price.close()

key_house_price = data_house_price[0].replace("\n","").split(",")

house_price = []

for lines in data_house_price[1:]:
    
    lines_house_price = lines.replace("\n","").split(",")
    
    dict_house_price = dict()
    
    for i in range(len(lines_house_price)):
        
        dict_house_price[key_house_price[i]] = lines_house_price[i]
    
    house_price.append(dict_house_price)

print(house_price)
```

i want to ask what's the meaning of replace and split in this key_house_price = data_house_price[0].replace("\n","").split(",")
and why the index is 0, and also what's the meaning behind this line -> for lines in data_house_price[1:] and
this line -> dict_house_price[key_house_price[i]] = lines_house_price[i]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you don't understand? Also note the `csv` module can do this for you.

Comment: thank you for replying, i want to ask what's the meaning of replace and split in this key_house_price = data_house_price[0].replace("\n","").split(",") and why the index is 0, and also what's the meaning behind this line -> for lines in data_house_price[1:] and this line ->  dict_house_price[key_house_price[i]] = lines_house_price[i], thank you

Comment: @jonrsharpe this looks like a school assignment, and as such it wouldn't be very educative to use a library for it.

Comment: @anna that's ~4 separate questions, many of which are covered by existing tutorials (see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) and documentation (strings methods: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've added comments to the answer to explain the flow, please add more details in your question if this is not clear enough :)

```py
# Open file for reading
file_house_price = open("house_price.txt", "r")

# read all lines from the file into a variable
data_house_price = file_house_price.readlines()

# as we're done with the file, we can safely close it (we have all the data in memory)
file_house_price.close()

# the first line of the data is the column headers separated by comma
# so here we split that line on comma (removing the newline character as well, using replace)
# which gives us a list of strings (each column header)
key_house_price = data_house_price[0].replace("\n","").split(",")

house_price = []

# loop over all the remaining lines from the file (the [1:] gives us all lines, except the first as indexing starts at 0)
for lines in data_house_price[1:]:
    
    # get rid of newline character and split the line on comma
    lines_house_price = lines.replace("\n","").split(",")
    
    # create a dictionary for storing data for this line
    dict_house_price = dict()
    
    # range gives as consecutive numbers from 0 to X-1
    # in this case, all valid indexes for the columns of the current line
    for i in range(len(lines_house_price)):
        
        # store each column value from the line using the column header we got before as key
        dict_house_price[key_house_price[i]] = lines_house_price[i]
    
    # add this lines information to the list of data
    house_price.append(dict_house_price)

# print collected data as output
print(house_price)
# (pretty formatted output):
#
# [{'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 50',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 15',
#   ' price': ' 500',
#   'land': '70'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 60',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 30',
#   ' price': ' 400',
#   'land': '70'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 60',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 55',
#   ' price': ' 300',
#   'land': '70'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 50',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 30',
#   ' price': ' 700',
#   'land': '100'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 70',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 25',
#   ' price': ' 1000',
#   'land': '100'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 70',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 50',
#   ' price': ' 650',
#   'land': '100'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 100',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 20',
#   ' price': ' 2000',
#   'land': '120'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 80',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 50',
#   ' price': ' 1200',
#   'land': '120'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 100',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 50',
#   ' price': ' 1800',
#   'land': '150'},
#  {'land': ''},
#  {' building': ' 90',
#   ' distance_to_center': ' 15',
#   ' price': ' 3000',
#   'land': '150'}]
```